# Как обновлять переменную с течением времени для каждого пользователя отдельно?

Tags: telebot, sqlite3

Всех приветствую.

Мой бот выполняет определённое действие после команды пользователя, но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы у пользователя было ограниченное количество использований этой команды, допустим 15. Но чтобы с течением времени количество использований увеличивалось, то есть +1 использование каждые 10 минут, пока не обновится до исходного значения в 15 использований. Но загвоздка ещё в том, что пользователи будут использовать команду не в одно время, то есть нельзя прибавлять 1 ко всем пользователям одновременно.

Спасибо.